# Monitoring rootless docker with cAdvisor

Tags: docker, cadvisor, rootless

I have setup docker to run in rootless mode following the instructions

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

I have some containers running fine with this setup. Now i want to setup monitoring via  cAdvisor starting cAdvisor in a container.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /:/rootfs:ro -v /var/run:/var/run:rw -v /sys:/sys:ro -v /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro --name=cadvisor google/cadvisor:latest
```

Clicking on 'docker containers' in the cAdvisor UI delivers the following result

> failed to get docker info: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Do i have to change the mounted volumes when running in rootless mode?

Answer (score 0):

When running rootless, your docker socket should be at

```
/run/user/$(id -u)/docker.sock
```

new cmdline will look like this:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /:/rootfs:ro -v /run/user/$(id -u)/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro -v /sys:/sys:ro -v ~/.local/share/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro:/var/lib/docker:ro --name=cadvisor google/cadvisor:latest
```

I don't think exposing cadvisor `8080:8080` is good idea, you need to do some restrictions on that port, like a firewall or change listening address to a more restricted interface.

Comment: This indeed makes the docker socket accessible to the non-privileged cAdvisor container, and the cAdvisor UI shows there are "19 containers" which in my case is correct. However it does not show details for these containers in the "Subcontainers" section, so it's still missing something. Suggestions from https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/1115 do not resolve the problem